# iOS archive not working

Tags: ios, archive, xcode9, codesign

I'm requesting your help to solve an archive issue for Apple iOS.

When I'm running the app with a local certificate everything is fine, but when I switch to archive (in order to publish it) I have an error.

Error is related with Alamofire and from what I consider with codesign

```
> Stripped
> /Users/..myuser../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/..myappname..-brxmobbquzmuhnbmcgzieifhgvjk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/...myprojectname.../InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//....app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
> of architectures: armv7 Code Signing
> /Users/...../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/......-brxmobbquzmuhnbmcgzieifhgvjk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/..../InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//.....app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework
> with Identity iPhone Developer: name (code) /usr/bin/codesign --force
> --sign 7FEA49779804D0F60707E9954A90FE65C  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/...../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.....-brxmobbquzmuhnbmcgzieifhgvjk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/...../InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//.....app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework'
> /Users/...../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/....-brxmobbquzmuhnbmcgzieifhgvjk/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/....../InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//......app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework:
> unknown error -1=ffffffffffffffff Command /bin/sh failed with exit
> code 1
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Did you tried clean , pod update , delete derived data and tried building

Comment: Hello, Kalamarico, after a long working night I solved the issue (keychain login password topic). Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Somehow the keychain password "login" was my problem. Changing it solved the signed issue. It was not related with Alamofire package.